# How can I get the id of a child element/

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the id of a child li element and see if that id contains the word "unit". Here is the segment of javascript that I have been working on:

```
insertSearchIcon: function(evt){
    var treeExists = $( '.jstree-icon' ).html();
    var currentTarget = $(evt.currentTarget);
    if (treeExists != null){                                                            //Check to see if tree exists
        var elementExists = document.getElementsByClassName( 'oob-dropdown' );
        zero = 0;
        if(elementExists.length == zero){                                                       //Check to see if button is already there
            var idOfParent = currentTarget.siblings('li').id;
            if(idOfParent.indexOf("unit") != -1){                                       //Check to see if element is not a unit
                currentTarget.$( '.jstree-leaf' ).prepend('<button class="oob-dropdown" id="oob-button"></button>');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to get the id that goes along with the ".jstree-leaf" under the ".jstree-icon" that was clicked:

```
<li id="unit-27404752" class="jstree-last jstree-open">
 <ins class="jstree-icon"> </ins><!--this one was clicked--> 
  <a href="#">
   <ul style="">
    <li id="unit-27404753" class="jstree-closed">
    <li id="unit-27404754" class="jstree-closed">
    <li id="unit-27404755" class="jstree-leaf">
    <ins class="jstree-icon"> </ins> <--!Not this one>
    <a class="" href="#">
    <ins class="jstree-icon" style="background: url("/api/mil2525/images/SFGPUUM----CUSG") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;"> </ins>
      S2 SEC 330 MED
     </a>
```

Comment: The `ins` element's `style` attribute will be an error if that's how it actually is and not just a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: When will the function `insertSearchIcon` be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the function works after I got it to work how I wanted, thanks for all the help.

```
insertSearchIcon: function(evt){
    var treeExists = $( '.jstree-icon' ).html();
    var currentTarget = $(evt.currentTarget);
    if (treeExists != null){                                                            //Check to see if tree exists
        var elementExists = document.getElementsByClassName( 'oob-dropdown' );
        zero = 0;
        if(elementExists.length == zero){                                               //Check to see if button is already there
            $('.jstree-leaf').each(function(){                                          //If not a unit put button
                var id = this.id;
                if (id.indexOf("unit") == -1){
                    $(this).prepend('<button class="oob-dropdown" id="oob-button"></button>');
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`jQuery.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) in combination with the attribute and the not selector. With this you get all elements whith the class `jstree-leaf` whose attribute `id` does not contain the word `unit`.

```
$(".jstree-leaf:not([id*='unit'])")
```

Then you can iterate over that elements if you want to retrieve their ids or do something with them:

```
$(".jstree-leaf:not([id*='unit'])").each(function() {
    // Do whatever you want with the id or the element.
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log("Found id: " + id);
}
```

Comment: this will grab all the leafs

Comment: $(this).find(".jstree-leaf").id; brings back undefined im trying $(this).find(".jstree-leaf").attr('id');

Comment: you need to use $.each

Comment: Assuming Current Target is the ins marked as clicked above, I don't think `find()` will work because the `<ins>` element does not wrap anything.

Comment: @SketchyTurtle you are I changed the answer.

Comment: @fnostro True, but I don't know which is the element that was clicked. Yours also is just an assumption. The questioner should change the selector to whatever is correct or tell us when the function `insertSearchIcon` will be called.

Comment: the `insertSearchIcon` is called everytime the jstree-icon is called. Also @Guillermo I am trying to find every `.jstree-leaf` that does not contain unit. I want to but something there when it isnt a unit, Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "when the jstree-icon" is called? Can you show us the surrounding code?
If you are looking for elements whose id does **not** contain the word `unit` you can use the [:not jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). I changed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(this).find(".jstree-leaf").each(function () { console.log($(this).attr('id'))});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not actually a child element, it's a sibling's child element.

You could use something like -

```
currentTarget.next("a").find(".jstree-leaf").whateverJQuery
```

Also, as I pointed out in the comments, the url property as it is in the example is breaking out of the quotes, try `'` inside the url or not using them at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('li[id^=unit-]', '.jstree-icon')` to check how many, if any, ids of `li` elements start with `unit-`, then use that fact in your `if` statement:

Change:

```
        var idOfParent = currentTarget.siblings('li').id;
        if(idOfParent.indexOf("unit") != -1){                                       //Check to see if element is not a unit
            currentTarget.$( '.jstree-leaf' ).prepend('<button class="oob-dropdown" id="oob-button"></button>');
        }
```

To:

```
        var idUnit = $('li[id^=unit-]', '.jstree-icon');
        if( idUnit.length ) {
            currentTarget.find( '.jstree-leaf' ).prepend('<button class="oob-dropdown" id="oob-button"></button>');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = $(".jstree-icon").next().children().children().attr("id");
if (a === "unit") {
   // do something
}
```